# Adding lines in data frame for each observation

Tags: r

I have a data structure in long format, meaning that each individual has more than one observation (and each observation has one row). Now each individual has a different number of observations. I would like to structure my data in the way, that each individual will have the same number of observations. Therefore, it would be great to find the individual with the most observations and add lines with LOCF (depending on the number of missing lines).

For example:

```
# simulate data structure
d <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3),
  value = c(10,11,12,5,9,55,14,12,20,7) )
```

Now individual 3 has the most observations (count = 5). I would like to add two lines for individual 1 (with 12 for value) and three lines for individual 2 (with 9 for value)

Any ideas?

Best wishes and thank you.

Comment: Why does individual 1 get its last value repeated two times while individual 2 gets individual 3's first value?

Comment: Sorry I changed that. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse solution.  If we create a variable to hold the within ID count using `seq_along` then we can use `complete` and `fill` to expand the table and fill in the missing values.

```
d |> group_by(id) |> 
     mutate(n = seq_along(value)) |>
     ungroup() |>
     complete(id, n) |>
     fill(value) |> 
     select(-n)

# A tibble: 15 × 2
      id value
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1    10
 2     1    11
 3     1    12
 4     1    12
 5     1    12
 6     2     5
 7     2     9
 8     2     9
 9     2     9
10     2     9
11     3    55
12     3    14
13     3    12
14     3    20
15     3     7
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you wish to carry forward the last value for each individual you could do

```
d$seq=ave(d$id,d$id,FUN=seq_along)
d=merge(
  d,
  merge(
    aggregate(value~id,data=d,FUN=tail,1),
    data.frame("seq"=1:max(table(d$id))),
    how="cross"
  ),
  by=c("id","seq"),
  all.y=T
)
d$value=ifelse(is.na(d$value.x),d$value.y,d$value.x)
d=d[,!grepl("value.",colnames(d))]

   id seq value
1   1   1    10
2   1   2    11
3   1   3    12
4   1   4    12
5   1   5    12
6   2   1     5
7   2   2     9
8   2   3     9
9   2   4     9
10  2   5     9
11  3   1    55
12  3   2    14
13  3   3    12
14  3   4    20
15  3   5     7
```